# Speech recognition in Windows universal app

Tags: speech-recognition, win-universal-app

I found different samples wich explain how to do it for Windows only, or for Windows phone only, but I'm looking for a library that would work with both, to share that code in a universal app. I found Windows.media and System.Speech but I can't make it work.
I would appreciate if someone could redirect me to such a sample.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.speechrecognition.aspx) is available for Windows Phone 8.1 and in the Universal API Contract for all Windows 10 devices. There is no in-box speech recognition for Windows 8.1 apps.

Start with the docs at [Responding to speech interactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn630426.aspx) and [Quickstart: Speech recognition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn630427(v=win.10).aspx) then look at the 
[Speech and text-to-speech sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/speechandtts) in the Universal Windows apps sample depository.